# Portrait/Vertical Youtube live video inside webview does not get proper height

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, safari, youtube-iframe-api

Devices i have tried it in: iPhone 11 iOS: 15, iPhone 6s iOS: 14, iPhone 8 iOS 14, Environment: App's webview, Safari, Chrome

We have followed iframe api reference(https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and using Youtube iframe in a webview accessible on our iOS app,
While live-streaming using youtube mobile app "go live" in portrait mode, on iOS, iFrame itself is of correct height (you can see youtube logo in bottom right) but the video inside iframe's its height is very small and is equivalent to a horizontal video.
WIDTH given to iFrame: 100vw
HEIGHT given to iFrame: 177vw. there is only iFrame on the page and nothing else

[IMAGE: Youtube vertical video Issue in IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5F8Z.png)

```
const DebugVertical = (props) => {
    const { videoId } = props.match.params;
    return (
        <iframe
        id={`youtube-embed-${videoId}`}
        src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&playsinline=1&rel=0&fs=0`}
        frameBorder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope"
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "177vw" }}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: You should be used in the height `vh` instead of `vw` for the height please check the CSS units here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp